# Retrieve column data from Pivot table using Python

Tags: python, pivot

I'm trying to retrieve all data from Pivot table in a excel sheet using Python Panda. I want to retrieve all the columns from the pivot table.

When I use DataFrame.get("column Name") it throws an Key error. But if I give "Unnamed: 1 or n"). it provides the data. I want to retrieve data save it as an normal table based spreadsheet so that I can create graphs and other items.
**Sample Code**:
df = pd.read_excel(filename.xlsx)
print(df.columns)

**Output**:
Index(['2023', 'Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4',
'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6', 'Unnamed: 7', 'Unnamed: 8', 'Unnamed: 9',
'Unnamed: 10', 'Unnamed: 11', 'Unnamed: 12', 'Unnamed: 13',
'Unnamed: 14', 'Unnamed: 15', 'Unnamed: 16', 'Unnamed: 17',
'Unnamed: 18', 'Unnamed: 19'],
dtype='object')

Since the spreadsheet has Pivot table with filters, it always gives the first row data as columns, rather than the actual column names from the pivot table.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Sam

Comment: Please provide example Data and Code used.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: pivottables, by default, don't start on row 1 of the sheet. so you should probably try using the `skiprows` parameter of `pd.read_excel()`.  you should probably also specify the sheet, but that apparently didn't cause any problems for you in your example